# SQL: non-overlapping dates

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

Considering this schema:

dept_manager(***emp_no:int, dept_no:string, from_date:date***, to_date:date)

Where the bold text represents the key.

I have to create a table based on this, enforcing some properties.

- One employee can only be the manager of one department at a time. This implies that the date entries in dept_manager table can not have overlaps for a certain employee.

I came so far for now, adding the CHECK constraint that ensures that the `from_date` comes before the `to_date`.

```
CREATE TABLE dept_manager (

emp_no INT NOT NULL,
dept_no CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
from_date DATE NOT NULL,
to_date DATE NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (emp_no, dept_no, from_date),
CHECK (from_date < to_date),
...
)
```

And now I have to add the part that ensures the asked condition. I thought about using FOREIGN KEYs but I don't know how I could add it.

Comment: In SQL Server I would use a check constraint with a user defined function to check if the dates overlap. I don't know if that's possible in postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trigger as well to check the date before insert

```
 CREATE TRIGGER dept_manager_trg
 BEFORE INSERT
     ON dept_manager
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE dept_manager_no_overlap();

 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dept_manager_no_overlap
 RETURNS trigger AS $BODY$

 BEGIN
    IF NEW.from_date > (SELECT q.to_date
                          FROM dept_manager d
                         INNER JOIN (SELECT emp_no
                                           ,max(to_date) as to_date
                                       FROM dept_manager
                                      GROUP BY emp_no) q
                            ON d.emp_no = q.emp_no
                           AND d.to_date = q.to_date
                         WHERE d.emp_no = NEW.emp_no)
       THEN RETURN NEW;
       ELSE RAISE EXCEPTION 'Overlap Date';
    END IF;
 END;
```